# Issues with validation

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have some issues with validation.When i am submitting the form, the **form.is_valid():**
always returns **false**.
After modifying the form i.e. after removing all validations from the form, it still return the false(my form is not submitted)

the code of html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block extrahead %}
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#id_birthday" ).datepicker();
    });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<form action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}

<div class="register_div">

    <p><label for="username">Username:</label></p>


    <p>{{ form.username }}</p>
</div>
<div class="register_div">

    <p><label for="email">Email:</label></p>
    <p>{{ form.email }}</p>
</div>
<div class="register_div">

    <p><label for="password">Password:</label></p>
    <p>{{ form.password }}</p>
</div>
<div class="register_div">

    <p><label for="password1">Verify Password:</label></p>
    <p>{{ form.password1 }}</p>
</div>
<div class="register_div">

    <p><label for="birthday">Birthday:</label></p>
    <p>{{ form.birthday }}</p>
</div>
<div class="register_div">
    <p><label for="name">Name:</label></p>
    <p>{{ form.username }}</p>
</div>
<p><input type="submit" value="submit" alt="register"/></p>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

the code of forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms import ModelForm
from drinker.models import Drinker

class RegistrationForm(ModelForm):
       username   = forms.CharField(label=(u'User Name'))
       email      = forms.EmailField(label=(u'Email Address'))
       password   = forms.CharField(label=(u'Password'), widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False))
       password1   = forms.CharField(label=(u'Verify Password'), widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False))

       class Meta:
              model=Drinker
              exclude=('user',)

       def clean_username(self):
                username=self.cleaned_data['username']
                try:
                      User.objects.get(username=username)
                except User.DoesNotExist:
                      return username
                raise forms.ValidationError("The Username is already taken, please try another.")
       def clean_password(self):
                password=self.cleaned_data['password']
                password1=self.cleaned_data['password1']
                if password1 != password:
                    raise forms.ValidationError("The Password did not match, please try again.")
                return password

class LoginForm(forms.Form):
      username  = forms.CharField(label=(u'User Name'))
      password  = forms.CharField(label=(u'Password'), widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False))
```

and the code of views.py

```
def DrinkerRegistration(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
         return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
    if request.method == 'POST':
         form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
         #return render_to_response('register')
         if form.is_valid():
                  user=User.objects.create_user(username=form.cleaned_data['username'], email=form.cleaned_data['email'], password = form.cleaned_data['password'])

                  user.save()
 #                 drinker=user.get_profile()
  #                drinker.name=form.cleaned_data['name']
   #               drinker.birthday=form.cleaned_data['birthday']
    #              drinker.save()
                  drinker=Drinker(user=user,name=form.cleaned_data['name'],birthday=form.cleaned_data['birthday'])  
                  drinker.save()    
                  return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
         else:
                  return render_to_response('register.html',{'form':form} , context_instance=RequestContext(request))  
    else:
         ''' user is not submitting the form, show them a blank registration form '''

         form = RegistrationForm()
         context={'form':form}
         return render_to_response('register.html',context , context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

the model code

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
class Drinker(models.Model):
       user     =models.OneToOneField(User)
       birthday =models.DateField()
       name     =models.CharField(max_length=100)

       def __unicode__(self):
             return self.name

#create our user object to attach to our drinker object

def create_drinker_user_callback(sender, instance, **kwargs):
      drinker, new=Drinker.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
post_save.connect(create_drinker_user_callback, User)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see two possible reasons:

1. Your template contains two usages of `username`: once at the top and once at the bottom. The form might fail because this does not fit into a single `CharField`.
2. It's hard to say without your model class, but maybe it contains fields you haven't explicitly excluded?

If it's not option 1, could you post your `Drinker` model as well?

Comment: ok i posted my model, when i submit my form it fives the error of **KeyError at /register/

'password1' **

Comment: without the entire stacktrace it's hard to tell, but I think it's the fact that your `ModelForm` has a `password1` field, while your underlying model does not have that field.  

Maybe in this case a `ModelForm` is not what you're looking for; instead, try using a normal Form as explained in the Django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/forms/

Comment: if u dont mind can you give me your mail id so that I can mail you my code and you can track the in better way.

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked the errors reporting while validating?

use `print form.errors` and check your console for error messages

Comment: ya. It always shows key error at password1.But when i deleted this field and remove all validations still the form is not submitted.my view is shown above i have used a line `return render_to_response('register')
` this line is executed if i comment the rest code means method is post,thus i have concluded that `if form.is_valid():` always return false and its else part is executed

Answer (score 0):

If your code changes aren't reflecting in the run environment, look at removing your *.pyc files. These sometimes can get cached.

For linux OS you can run the following from the root of your project;

```
find . -iname "*.pyc" -exec rm -f {} \;
```